# How to prove apparently trivial results in number theory

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Suppose I wish to prove a one-to-one correspondence between odd and even numbers. Thereby I will conclude their density is the same.

I can say that each number of the form $2n$ has a corresponding number $2n+1$ but that proves nothing in my opinion. For example each even number has an *infinitude* of corresponding odd numbers, e.g. $2n+3$, $2n+5$, etc.

As an amateur with an interest in such things, how would such a proof go? I don't mind how technical the notation. I'd just like to see what a formal proof of the proposition would look like.

Comment: One-to-one correspondence does not imply that the density is the same. For example are the prime numbers in one-to-one correspondence with the integers, but the first one has density zero, while the later has density one.

Comment: All you have to do is show there exists a bijection between them. The map $f(n)=n+1$ is bijective and maps odds to evens so your done.

Comment: It seems to me you're in search of a definition, not a proof.

Comment: It's not number $a$ *may* correspond to an infinite number of numbers.  It's that under *one* specific rule, $2n$ corresponds, by the rule, to $2n+1$ and by *that* rule, it doesn't correspond to any other.  We aren't interested in that we can correspond $2n$ to every odd number (we can also correspond it to ever prime number and every elephant in the zoo if we want).  It's that we can find *a* rule that maps each even to exactly one odd end each odd mapped for exactly one even.  $2n\mapsto 2n+1$ is one such rule.  $2n\mapsto 7-2n$ is another.

Answer (score 1):

A one-to-one correspondence between sets of integers only shows that if one set is infinite, so is the other.  The density you are talking of is the [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density), which is a much finer comparison.  As you suggest, you can make a one-to-one correspondence between the naturals and the squares, but the natural density of the squares is zero.  To prove two natural densities are the same, you need to show that the fractions below a number $N$ converge to the same number.  Here, if you do not include $0$ you can say the number of odds up to $N$ is $\frac N2$ or $\frac {N+1}2$, so the difference from a density of $\frac 12$ decreases as $\frac 1{2N}$.  As $N \to \infty,$ this goes to $0$

Answer (score 1):

Good intro to the concept of density here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

I'm also an amateur, but a proof would look like this:

Consider a set $A \subset \mathbb N$. Define a counting function $a(n)$ as the number of natural numbers in $A$ that are less than or equal to $n$. Then the natural density of $A$,

$$d(A) = \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{a(n)}{n}$$

If you count the even numbers less than $n$, for a large $n$, you get $a(n)\sim\frac{n}{2}$. If you count the odd numbers, you also get $a(n) \sim\frac{n}{2}$. Therefore they have the same natural density.

Answer (score 0):

Say each *specific* even number $2n$, determined by a *specific* $n$,  has one, and *only* one corresponding odd number $2n+1$, determined by the *same* $n$, and *not* any other odd number.

So $6 = 2*3$ corresponds to $7=2*3+1$ but it does *not* correspond to $9=2*3 + 3$ because $2*3 + 3\ne 2*3 + 1$.  And $6=2*3$ does not correspond to $11 = 2*5 + 1$ because $2*3 +1 \ne 2*5 + 1$.

I think you are confusing a correspondence being a rule to connect odd to evens (there are an infinite number of such correspondences),  each number corresponding to only one.

There are an infinite number of ways to map *each* even number to a specific odd number, but once you pick a way  *stick with it*!  You are not allowed to then change to another way.

So you can correspond $2n$ to $2n + 39$ if you want.  But once you *do* that it is set in stone.  You can't then change your mind and correspond $2n$ to $2n+1$.  The correspondence is *one* rule.  There are an infinitude of possible rules, but within each rule, each even number is *only* mapped to one odd number.